# Python regular expression split with \W

Tags: python, unicode

In Python document, I came across the following code snippet

```
>>> re.split('\W+', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', 'words', 'words', '']
>>> re.split('(\W+)', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.', '']
```

What I am confusing is that \W matches any character which is not a Unicode word character, but ',' is Unicode character. And what does the parentheses mean? I know it match a group but there is only one group in the pattern. Why ', ' is also return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"any character which is not a Unicode word character" is a character being part of a *word*: letter or digit basically.

Comma cannot be part of a word.

And comma is included in the resulting list because the split regex is into parentheses (defining a *group* inside the split regex). That's how `re.split` works (That's the difference between your 2 code snippets)

Comment: I see. So comma is a Unicode character, it's just not a word character. Thanks!